# Find all M such that MA+MB = const.

Tags: geometry

If AB = 4, find all points M in the plan such that MA+MB=5. It seems to me that all these points form something like an elipse, but I don't know if this is right, because the elipse formula contains squares of MA and MB. Can anybody help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: It's better than "something like" an ellipse - it is an ellipse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse

Comment: The equation for an ellipse involves squares, yes, but does its defining geometric property (the one about distances)?

Comment: It would make it a lot easier to help you with your confusion if you edit the answer to contain "the ellipse formula" with squares in it that you're speaking about.

Comment: This is the geometric definition of an ellipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mis-impression:  An ellipse is the locus of points $M$ such that the sum of the distances (not the squares of the distances) from points $A$ and $B$ is some constant greater than the distance between $A$ and $B$.

The locus of points $M$ such that the sum of the  *squares* of the distances) from points $A$ and $B$ is some constant greater than half of square of the distance between $A$ and $B$ happens also to be a very special sort of ellipse, namely a circle.